# SASS rule reuse

Tags: css, sass

I have a set of icons with different colors and each color is used with different status declared with CSS classes. For example, `<span class="icon icon--app"><span>` gives a gray app icon while `<span class="icon icon--app icon__light icon__selected"><span>` gives a white app icon.

The following code is written in SCSS.

```
span.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;

    &.icon--app {
        background: url(../images/app_gray.png);

        &.icon__selected {
            background: url(../images/app.png);
        }

        &.icon__light {
            background: url(../images/app_gray.png);

            &.icon__selected {
                background: url(../images/app_white.png);
            }
        }
    }

    &.icon--device {
        background: url(../images/device_gray.png);

        &.icon__selected {
            background: url(../images/device.png);
        }

        &.icon__light {
            background: url(../images/device_gray.png);

            &.icon__selected {
                background: url(../images/device_white.png);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, there's a long list of CSS rules as above, which shares much similarity for `app` and `device` and other icons. I wonder if I can simplify these CSS rules using SASS?

Comment: Have you examined the CSS to see if it is generating the styles you're expecting?  I suspect it is generating more than necessary.  This question might be a better fit for CodeReview.SE (you should be able to petition a mod to have it transfered).

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell your intent from this code. I compiled your SASS and it produced [this CSS](https://gist.github.com/abitdodgy/297d063a41d6f1d4614a). Not a lot of repetition there. Just a couple of background declarations. Although you can wrap this in a mixin to cut down on the type declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a mixin for you:

```
@mixin icon($type) {
  &.icon--#{$type} {
    background: url(../images/#{$type}_gray.png);

    &.icon__selected {
      background: url(../images/#{$type});
    }

    &.icon__light {
      background: url(../images/#{$type});

      &.icon__selected {
        background: url(../images/#{$type}_white.png)
      }
    }
  }
}

span.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;

  @include icon(app);

  @include icon(device);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use `mixin` in Sass:

e.g.

```
@mixin icon($type) {
    .icon-#{$type} {
        background: url(../images/#{$type}_gray.png);
    }
}

@include icon(app);
@include icon(device);
```

Comment: Upvote for having an eerily similar mixin declaration to mine!

Comment: @hedgerh And also a eerily similar answer time! :)